# Shorten links created using asp:repeater and Buildlink(Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asked a question similar to this before, where I needed the link changed to something else, but I actually need to shorten the link instead of replacing it.

So I need to shorten links, when they are longer than...say...50 characters. I know how to change the link but can't figure out how to shorten it.

For example: http://www.google.com would shorten to something like http://google...

My code:

```
<%# BuildLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(),Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%>
```

I've done this, which replaces the link. But I need to shorten it, instead of replacing it.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"  
    NavigateUrl='<%# BuildLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(), Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%>'>
    My Link    
</asp:HyperLink>
```

My `BuildLink` method:

```
public string BuildLink(string baseUrl, string taskInstanceId)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl))
    {

        string parms =
            "taskinstanceid=" + taskInstanceId +
            "&callback=" + GetCallBackUrl();

        string url = baseUrl.Contains("?")
            ? baseUrl + "&" + parms
            : baseUrl + "?" + parms;

        bool isUnc = false;
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(baseUrl);
            isUnc = uri.IsUnc;
        }
        catch {  }

        string link;
        if (isUnc)
        {
            link = "<a href='" + baseUrl + "' >" + baseUrl + "</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            link = "<a href='" + url + "' >" + baseUrl + "</a>";
        }
        return link;
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is the current view. Everything where it belongs
[image]

This is the view that's generated with the code JF gave
[image]

Also, the links are shortened even though they aren't 50> which is odd... I dislike asp repeaters.

Comment: Thanks. Does that work as is? Does a clickable (albeit un-shortened) hyperlink appear? I can't imagine adding a `<a href=...` as the NavigateUrl would work properly.

Comment: I apologize, I think I misread your question. I assume the only part you want shortened is the text of the link, not the actual link itself, correct? The concern of my previous comment still stands, however, it just isn't related to the question at hand. Sorry.

Comment: Currently the link does work, it just creates the link called "my link" under the URL that the eval() grabs. I just want to shorten the link, but still link to the place it is supposed to. So in my example above, "http://google..." will still link to http://google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `<asp:Hyperlink>` also gives you the ability to set the text to be displayed. So similar to how you build the link, you can also trim the text.

First, set the `text` attribute. You can also remove the text from in between the hyperlink tags as the `text` attribute does this for you.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"  
    NavigateUrl='<%# BuildLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(), Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%>'
    Text='<%# TrimLink(Eval("TaskDefinition.Url").ToString(), Eval("TaskInstanceID").ToString())%>'>  
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Then, create your code behind method. In this method, do you logic to get the *full* text of the URL that will be displayed. Check the length of that text. If the length is longer than 50, `Substring()` it to 50 characters and concatenate some ellipsis onto it.

```
public string TrimLink(string baseUrl, string taskInstanceId)
{
    string urlText = "";

    // do your logic to get the full url

    if(urlText.Length > 50)
    {
        urlText = urlText.Substring(0, 50);
        urlText = urlText + "...";
    }

    return urlText;
}
```

Instead of returning an entire hyperlink to be used as the URL for the `<asp:Hyperlink>`, try returning just the URL instead. I'm wondering if all the extra characters are unintentionally being used as closings for other controls. In `BuildLink`, do this instead.

```
if (isUnc)
{
    link = baseUrl;
}
else
{
    link = url;
}
return link;
```

Comment: Will test and get back to you. Thanks in the meantime

Comment: This doesn't work. I know why, but I can't think of how to fix the problem. Since you call eval both in the buildlink and the trimlink, it calls separate items because it calls the next item in the list (I believe). I might try to see if I can include your trimlink code inside my buildlink function.... Maybe

Comment: What doesn't work? It seems to be working for me. You should be able to stick a breakpoint in there and see what the values are. Should be all the same item, not the next until you get to the next row.

Comment: For example, Link A is appearing on Row A, but Link B is appearing on Row C. Link C is appearing on Row F. From then on, the links don't even appear and my table becomes ALL messed up.

Comment: That is strange. Definitely something else going on. Is the text wrong or is the URL wrong or both? What appears as the link text and link URL for "Link B"? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Give me like 3-4 minutes. Going to get some screenshots and post in main post.

Comment: Check out my edit. Give that a shot. I've tested this on my own and everything works as I would expect. Make sure you're setting some breakpoints and debugging this. Try to find out where conditions are/aren't being met that you would expect.

Comment: AYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

Thanks man. Works like a charm.